# What is the proper way to form this multi-dimensional array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to perform a series of requests that will organize the results in a given date span in a way where each location will live on the top level, and contain an another array with each set of results. Here is what I have so far:

```
locations = Location.all
@requests = []
locations.each do |location|
    request = PurchaseRequest.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ? AND location_id = ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date], location.id).order(:location_id)
    @requests.push(location => request)
end
```

My ideal (non-working) implementation in the view would look something like:

```
<ul>
<% @requests.each do |location| %>
    <li>location[0].name</li>
    <ul>
        <% location[1].each do |request| %>
            <li>request.name</li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@requests = {}
Location.all.each do |location|
  @requests[location.name] = PurchaseRequest.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ? AND location_id = ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date], location.id).order(:location_id)
end
```

and:

```
<ul>
  <% @requests.each do |location_name, request_list| %>
    <li><%= location_name %></li>
    <ul>
      <% request_list.each do |request| %>
        <li><%= request.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

`@requests` becomes a hash with the key being the location name and the value being the purchase requests.